# How do I send data to the Microsoft Loopback Adapter?

Tags: windows-7, networking, loopback

I have a Microsoft Loopback Adapter installed and I have a program that listens to data on this adapter.

But how exactly do I send data to this loopback adapter in Windows? There must be some tool which will help me to send data. How do people test a loopback adapter in Windows 7?

Comment: Can't you just send the data to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Not really. I have an application that listens to this address and forwards this data onto a slip connection connected to a MCU.